# mat-paginator not working well with [hidden]

Tags: angular, angular-material

Recently when I worked with "mat-table" , had to use "mat-paginator" and found out that the [hidden] attribute does not have any effect on it.
Then i ended up using

> `<mat-paginator [ngStyle]="{display: nodes.length >0 ? 'block' : 'none'}" [pageSize]="50" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 25, 50, 100]">`

on the contrary *ngIf is working, But.. its giving me trouble with dynamic data and observable.

Any thoughts on how to do it right please??

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me just now:

1. Add a new element (such as a div) as a parent of the mat-paginator
2. Add the [hidden] attribute and condition to the parent div element

For example:

```
<div [hidden]="nodes.length <= 0">
  <mat-paginator [pageSize]="50" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 25, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

This seems to work with dynamic data as well.

Answer (score 0):

[hidden] attribute makes the element's visibility none but the DOM element is added to HTML and somehow the property display: none is overridden by other parent CSS rules.

in the case of *ngIf, the element is not created in DOM. so other CSS rules do not apply.

*ngIf approach is perfect.

Comment: As i mentioned , When am using ngIf , the paginatior  is coming as undefined  when data getting populated to the Table.Which makes pagination useless.

Answer (score 0):

[hidden] property of Paginator didn't works for me. My solutions is:

In template:

```
 <mat-paginator
  [ngClass]="{ hiddenElement: (dataSource.counter | async) === 0 }"
```

Where counter is a BehaviorSubject with number of page elements.
In styles I've added class:

```
.hiddenElement {
  display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in the comments above, hidden won't work with mat-paginator, if you really need to use ngIf, the solution I found was to put a timeout in the paginator, like this:

```
ngOnChanges() {
this.dataSource.data = this.items;
setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);}
```

this will work, although I believe it's not the best approach.